# Android : read web content of xml string

Tags: android

I try to read web content of xml string where produce from PHP Code. Here the [result](http://www.sbmgrp.co.id/website/getxml/product.php). But its keep my application crash. It's same when t tried to read www.yahoo.com too.

Here's my code

```
public static void downloadString(String urlString,String saveLoc, String fileName){
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
            //URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            int code = conn.getResponseCode();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            String fullFileName = saveLoc + "//" + fileName;
            File file = new File(fullFileName);

            if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {bw.write(inputLine);}

            bw.close();
            br.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I tried to debug and cannot pass from

> int code = conn.getResponseCode();

I dont know what exacty the error. Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use volley library.

Add these two dependencies in your build.gradel file:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

And then add this to your java file:`

```
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {

            gson = new Gson();
            s=s.substring(10,s.indexOf(']')+1)+"}]";
            Log.d("Error",s);
            list = (List) gson.fromJson(s, List.class);
            postTitle = new String[list.size()];

            for(int i=0;i<list.size();++i){
                mapPost = (Map<String,Object>)list.get(i);
                //mapTitle = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("url");
                postTitle[i] = (String) mapPost.get("url");


               // ArrayList<String> list= (ArrayList<String>) mapPost.get("categories");

               // postTitle[i] =  mapPost.get("categories");

                //postTitle[i]  = TextUtils.join(", ",(ArrayList<String>) mapPost.get("url"));

            }

            postList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,postTitle));
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    rQueue.add(request);




// get the total post

//mapPost = (Map<String,Object>)list.get(i);


//get Post Title

//mapTitle = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("title");

// postTitle[i] = (String) mapTitle.get("rendered");


//get post id

//to string: postTitle[i] = Integer.toString( (( 
Double)mapPost.get("id")).intValue());

//to integer: int postID = ((Double)mapPost.get("id")).intValue();


//get post date

//postTitle[i] = (String) mapPost.get("date");

//post link
//postTitle[i] = (String) mapPost.get("link");

//get post author
//to string: postTitle[i] = Integer.toString( (( 
Double)mapPost.get("author")).intValue());
//to integer: int postID = ((Double)mapPost.get("author")).intValue();
```

I would also recommend you to see some tutorials on volley.

My parsing URL was this: [Bing Wallpaper Image.xml](http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=5)

Comment: sorry, i dont really get this...how to use this code ?

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/wordpress-to-android-app-tutorial/  see this web page.

Answer (score 0):

add this two lines.

```
public static void downloadString(String urlString,String saveLoc, String fileName){
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
     conn.setRequestMethod("GET"); //this lines
     conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");//this lines
     int code = conn.getResponseCode();
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            String fullFileName = saveLoc + "//" + fileName;
            File file = new File(fullFileName);

            if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {bw.write(inputLine);}

            bw.close();
            br.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: still error, or i miss something beside 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: did you give INTERNET permisssion ??

Comment: Yes, i also try another way like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442546/get-error-in-http-url-connection) its doesn;t work too... any advice please